# Get Extent of Complicated Data Structure in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, extent

I am trying to get the extent of my xy-data which has this nested form:

```
data = [
        {"points": [{"x": 0, "y": 0}, {"x": -5, "y": 100}, {"x": 300, "y": 1}, ...],
         "rgbval": "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
        },
        {"points": [{"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"x": -7000, "y": 2}, {"x": 0, "y": 0}, ...],
         "rgbval": "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
        }, 
         .
         .
         .
       ]
```

In the case of this sample data, the values I'm looking for are:

```
x_domain = [-7000, 300]
y_domain = [0, 100]
```

I am able to get the extent of a particular group of points using:

```
for i in [0...data.length]
    console.log(d3.extent(data[i].points, (d) -> d.x))  # x_domain of i_th group of points
    console.log(d3.extent(data[i].points, (d) -> d.y))  # y_domain of i_th group of points
```

In the sample case, this would give me two x_domains and two y_domains. I want the domains of the overall xy data.

Comment: Wait, is there a tag for `extent`? Apparently there is a tag for everything at S.O.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, merge the arrays using [d3.merge](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#merge) (which is pretty much a fancy `concat`):

```
var merged = d3.merge(data.map(function(d){ return d.points}));
```

Then, just get the extent the normal way:

```
var xExtent = d3.extent(merged, function(d){ return d.x});
var yExtent = d3.extent(merged, function(d){ return d.y});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
  "points": [{
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  }, {
    "x": -5,
    "y": 100
  }, {
    "x": 300,
    "y": 1
  }],
  "rgbval": "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
}, {
  "points": [{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2
  }, {
    "x": -7000,
    "y": 2
  }, {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  }],
  "rgbval": "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
}];

var merged = d3.merge(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.points
}));

var xExtent = d3.extent(merged, function(d) {
  return d.x
});
var yExtent = d3.extent(merged, function(d) {
  return d.y
});

console.log("x extent: " + xExtent);
console.log("y extent: " + yExtent);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: don't mistake this uncommon `d3.merge` for the way more famous `selection.merge`.